# Free or Cheap Accounting Program Required for Windows

Tags: windows, accounting

I am looking for a small light duty accounting program to use at home for my investments.  A General Ledger is probably necessary.  It must be able to import bank statements in some form.

I dont mind paying a reasonable cost, but I am not intrested in a recurring cost.

It needs to run on Windows.

Comment: What OS should it run on?

Comment: Is GL "General Ledger"?

Comment: @Mawg, Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried GNU Cash and Wave.  My main problem with Wave is that they own my data.  I want my data on my pc.  Which is where GNU Cash shines.  However, there are basic usability issues with both.  To handle Sales Tax is not too bad.  But purchase Tax is a nightmare.  Every transaction has to be split in GnuCash, and Wave is not much better.  I tried a few others as well.

I have finally settled on **"Cashbook Complete"** at https://www.acclaim.co.nz/.  The price is between NZD85-340, a once only payment.  The file is on my machine.  I don't mind paying.  The **UI** is very usable, but some of the **UI** is very 70s.  However, I prefer function over beauty.  It imports statements, and its rules are so simple to set up and work amazingly well.  Once set up, it automatically splits items if required into multiple accounts.

*Disclaimer - I am not related to it in any way.*

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Cash](https://www.gnucash.org/) and [Wave](https://www.waveapps.com/) is pretty sweet. Both free and imports galore.

If it is for personal finance I would Highly recommend [Mint](https://www.mint.com/) or [Personal Capital](https://www.personalcapital.com/).

Comment: I tried both but I dont like them. But I am going to leave the tick